# R: Compute column members efficiently in character matrices

Tags: r

I have 12 character matrices with various length from 2 to 13 row length.

For example, with 2 row length (I only show partially):

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
[1,] "N"  "N"  "S"  "S"  "F"  "F"  "C"  "S"  "C"  "S"   "U"   "N"   "S"   "S"   "S"   "S"  
[2,] "N"  "C"  "S"  "N"  "N"  "S"  "C"  "F"  "C"  "S"   "C"   "U"   "F"   "S"   "S"   "N"  
     [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30]
[1,] "S"   "S"   "N"   "S"   "S"   "U"   "S"   "C"   "C"   "S"   "C"   "S"   "S"   "S"  
[2,] "O"   "S"   "U"   "S"   "U"   "U"   "S"   "C"   "C"   "S"   "C"   "U"   "S"   "U"
```

Another example (5 row length) (partially shown):

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "F"  "S"  "U"  "C"  "U"  "S"  "S"  "N"  "S"  "N"  
[2,] "S"  "S"  "N"  "N"  "N"  "U"  "N"  "C"  "U"  "N"  
[3,] "S"  "S"  "C"  "S"  "N"  "S"  "S"  "C"  "N"  "C"  
[4,] "S"  "S"  "N"  "U"  "N"  "O"  "C"  "C"  "U"  "C"  
[5,] "N"  "O"  "O"  "U"  "N"  "O"  "U"  "C"  "C"  "C"
```

The maximum number of row is 13

The maximum number of column is 1354

The matrices contains 6 letters:

```
the_letters <- c("C","F","N","O","S","U")
```

I want to calculate:

How many column contains sequences of ("N","N")?

How many column contains sequences of ("F","S","S","N")?

And other possible combinations of `the_letters` for 2 to 13 lengths

for example, ("N","S"), 2 length
for example, ("N","S","O"), 3 length
etc.

(Note that the sequence matters & letters can be repeated).

How to do this efficiently?

Comment: Try `sum(colSums(m1 == "N") == 2)` and second csae `sum(colSums(m2 == c("F", "S", "S", "S", "N")))` and which is not clear though

Comment: Thank you, I have edited a little. Is it still not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data:

```
set.seed(1) 
the_letters <- c("C","F","N","O","S","U")
rows <- 5
cols <- 10
(foo <- matrix(sample(the_letters, size = rows*cols, replace = TRUE), rows, cols))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#> [1,] "F"  "U"  "F"  "N"  "U"  "N"  "N"  "S"  "S"  "S"  
#> [2,] "N"  "U"  "F"  "S"  "F"  "C"  "O"  "S"  "O"  "C"  
#> [3,] "O"  "O"  "S"  "U"  "O"  "N"  "N"  "C"  "S"  "N"  
#> [4,] "U"  "O"  "N"  "N"  "C"  "U"  "F"  "S"  "O"  "S"  
#> [5,] "F"  "C"  "S"  "S"  "F"  "N"  "S"  "N"  "O"  "S"
```

One approach is to paste the columns into a string and use `grepl` to find substrings. Here's a function that does this:

```
ncols_pattern <- function(x, pattern) {
  sum(grepl(pattern, apply(x, 2, paste0, collapse="")))
}
```

You specify your desired pattern as, say, `"NN"` rather than `c("N","N")`.

Examples:

```
ncols_pattern(foo, "O")
#> [1] 5
ncols_pattern(foo, "UN")
#> [1] 2
ncols_pattern(foo, "OO")
#> [1] 2
```